# Using NetworkX + Plotly to create a 3D Manipulable Network Graph in Python

Tags: python, networkx, plotly-python

I'm currently working on a project where I want to represent a networkx graph as a 3D graph in Plotly that I can manipulate, to be able to better see where all the connections are. I currently have my graph in this state with some sample data and it was pleasantly easy to get it to work:

[image: Graph State]

However, I'm running into some issues trying to implement the rest of the functionality that I want.

I've been reading documentation and I'm using a Scatter3d to create my graph.

Currently, I'm using this code here to render my graph

```py
def display_graph (graph) :
    spring = nx.spring_layout(graph, dim=3, k = 0.5)

    x_nodes = [spring[key][0] for key in spring.keys()]
    y_nodes = [spring[key][1] for key in spring.keys()]
    z_nodes = [spring[key][2] for key in spring.keys()]

    x_edges = []
    y_edges = []
    z_edges = []

    for edge in graph.edges():
        x_coords = [spring[edge[0]][0], spring[edge[1]][0], None]
        x_edges += x_coords

        y_coords = [spring[edge[0]][1], spring[edge[1]][1], None]
        y_edges += y_coords

        z_coords = [spring[edge[0]][2], spring[edge[1]][2], None]
        z_edges += z_coords
    
    trace_edges = go.Scatter3d(
        x=x_edges,
        y=y_edges,
        z=z_edges,
        mode='lines',
        line={'color': 'skyblue', 'width': 8},
        hoverinfo='none'
    )

    trace_nodes = go.Scatter3d(
        x=x_nodes,
        y=y_nodes,
        z=z_nodes,
        mode='markers',
        marker={'symbol': 'circle', 'size': 8, 'color': 'skyblue'},
        hoverinfo='text',
        hoverlabel={
            "bgcolor": "black",
            "bordercolor": "skyblue"
        },
        hovertext=list(spring.keys())
    )

    data = [trace_edges, trace_nodes]
    fig = go.Figure(data=data)
    
    fig.update_layout(
        scene={
            "xaxis": {"visible": False},
            "yaxis": {"visible": False},
            "zaxis": {"visible": False}
        },
        showlegend=False
    )

    fig.show(
        config={'displayModeBar': False}
    )
```

However, it's very difficult to judge depth in the current layout of this graph, and I would like to accomplish a few things:

- Merge the NetworkX graph to be undirected, and merge duplicate edges in this undirected graph to make only one edge between nodes that have edges with a larger weight depending on the number of undirected links between the nodes
- Correlate this edge weight to the width of the lines in the graph so that it's easier to see which nodes are referenced the most heavily
- Change the size of the markers in Plotly depending on the summed weight of every edge pointing to them so that more heavily referenced nodes render larger
- Markers should scale size based on the zoom of the camera and the distance to the nodes, so that each one has an "absolute" size in 3D space rather than a screen-space size
- Customize the hover elements on the different nodes to have more padding

Later on, I also want to be able to change the color of a node or nodes depending on a subset of the graph that I'm interested in analyzing (most likely a list of nodes from the NetworkX graph, as this is easy to create), and it would be ideal for graphical purposes if the edges to these nodes also became gradients between the skyblue color of the rest of the nodes and the color that I set these selected nodes to be (probably some shade of red) so that it doesn't look weird, as plotly's 3D rendering seems to inconsistently draw the edges on top or below the nodes themselves.